# Aurelia/Gulp- Protractor e2e config file2

Tags: aurelia, e2e-testing, gulp-protractor

Currently I am using Aurelia Esnext skeleton to build off my application. For end to end testing is there a way to use protractor's config file specs/suites arguments instead of the gulp task running all specs in alphabetical format?

```
gulp.task('e2e', ['build-e2e'], function(cb) {
   return gulp.src(paths.e2eSpecsDist + '**/*.js')
      .pipe(protractor({
         configFile: 'protractor.conf.js',
         args: ['--baseUrl', 'http://127.0.0.1:9000', '--inspect']
      }))
      .on('end', function() {
         process.exit();
      })
      .on('error', function(e) {
         throw e;
      });
});
```

Comment: I don't got your question completely. Do you only want to run a single spec via CLI? e.g. `gulp e2e --spec welcome.po.js`?

Comment: Oh I want to run a specific number of spec files like in the protractor config file